# Mysql query to get clients who have 3 or more then 3 order each of the last 3 month

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have this record:

*******order table**************

```
id         client           order_date
 5          7                 2015-12-27
 6          7                 2015-12-28
 8          7                 2015-12-27
 9          7                 2016-01-27
 10         7                 2016-01-28
 11         7                 2016-01-27
 12         7                 2016-02-27
 13         7                 2016-02-28
 14         7                 2016-02-27
 15         9                 2016-01-27
 16         9                 2016-01-27
 17         9                 2016-01-27
 18         9                 2016-02-02
 19         9                 2016-02-04
 20         9                 2016-02-04
 21         11                2015-12-27
 22         11                2015-12-27
```

I am trying to write a query:

```
SELECT count(*) as regular_client FROM 
( SELECT count(*) as totalCount, client 
  FROM order 
  where `order_date` >= (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
  GROUP BY `client`
) subq WHERE totalCount >= 3;
```

Expected Output:

```
regular_client
  2
```

Comment: your query is fine. Only one client was 3 or more times

Comment: Yes, i am expected 2 clients. but per month 3 or more then 3 order in last 3 month .

Comment: I think you mistake with test data for 9th client - change them  to 2016 :)

Comment: Oh, sorry i am some data mistake for 9th client  2015 -> replace 2016

Comment: Can you fix your question. Do you want to count the number of regular clients in the current month?

Comment: what is the problem with your current query?